# How can I fix hanging SSH on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, ssh

When I log in through SSH on my Raspberry PI 2 i can work for a couple seconds then the connection breaks. I get the error:

```
packet_write_wait
```

If I pin the host I get something like:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
64 bytes from 192.168.1.117: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=13.546 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.117: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=7.693 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.117: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=7.848 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
Request timeout for icmp_seq 15
```

Which if I can read correctly is somehow disconnected and then connects randomly at some point

I would like to figure out why this happens and prevent it from happening. My current setup is as follows:

- Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian, Wifi Dongle
- MacOSX connected to the
  same network

Comment: Have you tried changing channels on the wifi router? Or, temporarily to test, changing the pi location to ensure good wifi reception and transmission? My first hunch is maybe poor wifi reception. The other is power. Do you have anything else connected to the pi (via usb or pin) that may be taking power from the dongle?

Comment: the Pi is few feet away from router, so range is not the issue. No, I don't have anything else connected to it - just power and HDMI. I have not tested channels - how would I do that?

Comment: If you're that close wifi / radio interference may not be an issue. Can you hard wire in through your router with both pi and computer connected to same router? (A pain, I know but I'm just trying to eliminate other possibilities.)

Comment: @Richard When raspberry is wired with ethernet it works perfectly with stable pings of 0% loss and average under 3,4ms even if my computer is on Wifi